# comparing two string in for loop using if condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, cookies, comparison

i am working on javascript cookies and my **cookie name** is
**ssecname**
so i want to search my cookie using this code

```
function readcookie() {
var allcookies = document.cookie;
var cookiearray  = allcookies.split(';');         
for(var i = 0; i<=cookiearray.length; i++)
 {
  name =  cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
  coo_glo_value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
  alert(name); /* here it shows name value is equal to ssecname but not comparing below */
  if(name == "ssecname") /* i have tried === */
  {
     alert('here you go');
  }        
 } 
}
```

i dont know why its not comparing my string but when i do

```
  if(name != "ssecname")
  {
     alert('here you go');
  }
```

so it give me output here you go so i cant understand why its happening??
please help me and kindly tell some other way to compare..
Tahnks in advance :)

Comment: Maybe there is a space in the `name` that you haven't notice in the first alert? Try to debug it in firebug or chrome developer tools, and see if the length property is equal to 8 ('ssecname'- 8 chars). Or try this: `name.trim() == "ssecname"`

Comment: @Botis your answer to much logical thank you i am checking:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a [`foreach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
function readCookie() {
    var cookies = document.cookie;
    var cookieBundle = cookies.split(';');     

    for(var i in cookies) {
        var name = cookieBundle[i].split('=')[0],
            cookieValue = cookieBundle[i].split('=')[1];

        if(name.trim() == "csrftoken") {
            alert("Here you go.");
        }
    }
}

readCookie();
```

You can play with this on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtr6q/).

(Note: change your cookie name in the comparison).

### To knowledge

A `foreach` works very similar to a *normal* `for`. Its iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, *in arbitrary order*. For each distinct property, statements can be executed. (To get more about this function, [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).)

The `trim()` function I used based on [Botis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/709914/botis)' answer — its removes all empty spaces from a string.

Comment: Thank you veryyyyy much its working :) but can you tell me what is foreach?? n why i should use trim() for this??

Comment: @MaqboolUrRahimKhan The foreach is just a difrent version of the for loop. It iterates over all elements of the collection. The `Trim()` method removes all empty spaces from the string. See my comment on your question.